# Wordpress Gravity Forms, how to reset form field values after confirmation without page refresh

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I had a gravity form with Ajax submission. After form submission successfully, I would like to reset the form field values to let the user submit multiple times. And without page refreshing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Gravity Forms Reload Form plugin provides this functionality:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-reload-form/

It can either automatically reload after x seconds - or - you can create a reload link in the form confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone else are searching for a proper solution, this might do the trick.

I have been testing the Gravity Form API and a bunch of other reset solutions, and ended up with this jQuery solution:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        if($('#gform_18')) { //change to the ID of your form
            $("form").each(function(){
                $(this).find(':input').val('');
                $(this).find('.gfield_error').removeClass('gfield_error');
                $(this).find('.validation_message').remove();
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: How does this work for you @mathiasmadsen? The way I see Gravity Forms working with ajax submission is that after a form is submitted, then Gravity Forms removes the form from the DOM. Therefore, there are no input fields to reset/empty and there are no validation & error messages to remove. The form is replaced by a confirmation message, so your code does not seem to work when using ajax submission, not the way I see it. Please do elaborate on how you have made this work?

Comment: @VayuRobins Actually, my solution at the time of posting was bound in a setup where I needed to reset my form at various steps / pages of the form. Furthermore I was using Gravity Form PDF Previewer and ended up not actually submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mathiasmadsen. Your suggested solution, however, does not seem to be quite relevant to the question, so it confused me when I tested your code. I ended up using the Gravity Perks plugin linked to below and it worked perfectly.